# Performing bidirectional join queries on tables with one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanna have a bidirectional relationship between my two tables that are related by a one to many relationship.

So, i have a `User` table, with columns such as `user_id`, and `transaction_id` etc (and other user datails columns).

I have another table called `transaction` which has columns like `transaction_id` and  `user_id` (to refer to the user this particular transaction belongs to).

Now, the issue is, a particular user can have multiple transactions attached to them, which means, this transaction table can have multiple rows for the same user. This makes it easy for me to get user details via join query. But I want to make this relationship bi-directional.

As in, if all i have is user details, i should be able to get the transaction details of that person. but since, a user can have multiple transactions at once, I'm not able to write a join query.

As such, I am yet to figure out how to store two transaction id's for a particular user, keeping in mind that i should be able to make a join query having the user details (I could always store transaction id's in the form of an array, but that won't let my join query happen).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this table structures :

transactions

```
id
user_id
tdate
amount
```

user

```
id
name
email
```

you seem to be already aware that you can list all transactions of a user, along with his information, with :

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.name,
    u.email,
    t.id,
    t.tdate,
    t.amount
FROM 
    users u
    INNER JOIN transactions t ON t.user_id = u.id
WHERE
    u.id = ?
ORDER BY 
    u.id, 
    t.tdate
```

The question mark represents the `id` of the user whose transactions you want to see. This returns one record for each transaction of the user.

If you are looking to, for a given transaction, list all other transactions of the same user, then one solution is to add another join to the query : basically, this would first retrieve the given transaction by id (`t0`), and then list all transactions by the same user (`t`).

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.name,
    u.email,
    t.id,
    t.tdate,
    t.amount
FROM 
    users u
    INNER JOIN transactions t0 ON t0.user_id = u.id
    INNER JOIN transactions t ON t.user_id = u.id
WHERE
    t0.id = ?
ORDER BY 
    u.id, 
    t.tdate
```